# Get Tweets without t.co links

Tags: twitter, url-shortener

I am doing a twitter visualization.  All the tweets are displayed on a screen, but the user will not be able to "click" or interact with the tweets in anyway beside reading them.  Therefore, I want to get rid of all the tweets that use the `t.co` shortener.  Is there a way to do this on twitters end using their API or should I do it manually?

Comment: I think you should do it manually, using a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `include_entities` parameter, you'll get additional metadata attached to a Tweet, which contains all the necessary information you need to "hydrate" the t.co link into something suitable for display.  If you look at Twitter.com, you'll see that the t.co links are rendered in this manner.

The documentation for Tweet entities is available here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

Comment: not exactly what I wanted, but I guess I could check to see if the tweets have a expandable_url instead of using a regular expression...

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood what you wanted.  You don't want to display any Tweets with links at all?  How are you getting the feed of Tweets?

Comment: just be using twitter search api for a few keywords